# visual basic string implement

Tags: string, vba

Insert inverted comma ("") into string visual basic

```
Dim str As String

str = "*.doc" & "," & "*.docx"
```

I want the textbox show `"*.doc" & "," & "*.docx"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not at all clear what you're asking for. If you do that, the resulting string will be `*.doc,*.docx`. If you want the inverted comma (the quotation mark), you would do something like:

```
str = Chr$(34) & "*.doc" & Chr$(34) & "," & Chr$(34) & "*.docx" & Chr$(34)
```

That would yield something like

```
"*.doc","*.docx"
```

Is this what you are looking for? If not, let us know what you're trying to accomplish and we can help you out.

Answer (score 4):

Write the string as you want it represented:

```
str = "*.doc" & "," & "*.docx"
```

double the quotes to escape them:

```
str = ""*.doc"" & "","" & ""*.docx""
```

then quote the string entire:

```
str = """*.doc"" & "","" & ""*.docx"""

?str
"*.doc" & "," & "*.docx"
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me, try it.

```
Dim str As String = """ * .doc"" & "","" & ""*.docx """
TextBox1.Text = str
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested this with a messagebox and it worked fine for me.

```
Dim str As String = "*.doc" & "," & "*.docx"
textbox1.text = str
```

Answer (score 0):

**VB6 code:**

```
Dim str As String
str = "*.doc" & "," & "*.docx"
Text1.Text = str
```

**VB.net code:**

```
Dim str As String
str = "*.doc" & "," & "*.docx"
TextBox1.Text = str
```

Both of these work.